# How do I determine whether an array contains the whole/part of array of string?

Tags: javascript

How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in string or consist the whole array of string ?

For example

```
const list = ['appple','orange','burger','pizza']
```

by includes, I can check if particular value exist in list

But how can I check with a list of string

like

```
const listToCheck = ['appple','orange']

list.includes(listToCheck)  <= gives me true


const listToCheck = ['appple','orange','pineapple']

list.includes(listToCheck)  <= gives me true
```

Comment: you have typos: "cosnt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `every()` or `some()` with `includes()`, depending on your needs:

```js
const list = ['apple', 'orange', 'burger', 'pizza'];

const listToCheck1 = ['apple', 'orange'];
const listToCheck2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'];
const listToCheck3 = ['pineapple', 'mango'];

const every1 = listToCheck1.every(item => list.includes(item)); 
const every2 = listToCheck2.every(item => list.includes(item)); 
console.log("every1",every1)
console.log("every2",every2)

const some1 = listToCheck1.some(item => list.includes(item)); 
const some2 = listToCheck2.some(item => list.includes(item)); 
const some3 = listToCheck3.some(item => list.includes(item)); 
console.log("some1",some1);
console.log("some2",some2);
console.log("some3",some3);
```

- `some()` is like an `union`. It checks if any element in one array exists in the other array
- `every()` is like an `intersection`. It checks if all elements in one array are also in the other array.

Comment: sorry, my bad, Actually i want to say if part of it is correct, then i should also pass it. is it possible to do it?

Comment: @AeLeung just use `some` instead of `every`

Comment: @pilchard, i added your comment to the answer.

Comment: That's great, but you should actually vote to close as duplicate

Comment: Yeah, this question had to be common, i saw your comment with link.